# How to create a notification in a LocationListener

Tags: android, android-notifications

i try to send a notification when the gps is enabled - therefore i create a service which is listening if the provider is enabled or not. It works fine and react when i change the gps state but did not create the notification

```
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GPS switched on ");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (!gpsNoteActiv) {
                gpsNoteActiv = true;
                Notification.Builder nb = gpsNotification.getAndroidChannelNotification("GPS aktiviert", "Ihr GPS Signal ist eventuell unbeabsichtigt aktiviert");
                gpsNotification.getManager().notify(101, nb.build());
            }
        }
    }
```

I get some notifications in the logcat, i'll post at the bottom.. Is there a similar way to post notifications like i tried?

```
? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.apps.gmm.locationsharing.usr.LocationAvailabilityChecker$LocationProvidersChangedBroadcastReceiver
? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.NlpNetworkProviderSettingsUpdateReceiver
? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
? W/BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED flg=0x10 } to com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.broadcastreceiver.external.ExternalCommonBroadcastReceiver
? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
```

Comment: This needs to be a foreground service on Android 8.0+, so you will already be showing a `Notification`. Do you really want to show a second one?

Comment: Hi, first thanks for the answer! Do you have a advise how i can change the service?

Comment: Well, I recommend that you read [the docs on background service limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) that I referred to in my previous comment. And I recommend that you read [the docs on background location limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits), to confirm that your app will be able to work on Android 8.0+. In both cases, you are going to need [a foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

Comment: Thanks, i see i have a lot to do ^^ Happy new year!